# How to Check Programmatically,whether any fingers are enrolled or not in Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows-7, biometrics, credential-providers

i am programming in windows 7 using c#.

i am developing WBF Application for enrollment.

i want to check whether any fingerprint enrolled or not in that system.

i also tried getenablesetting function.but it only gives biometric option enabled or not.but
 i want to know fingerprint enrolled or not?

How to achieve this?